# Let $ G $ be a non-trivial group having at least one finite order element. Show that your Cayley graph can not be a tree.

Tags: graph-theory

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Let $G$ be a non-trivial group having at least one finite order element and 
$S$ any set of generators. Show that your Cayley graph can not be a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is that element and $g^n=e$, consider a path $P$ from $e$ to $g$ 
in the Cayley graph. Then $gP$ is a path from $g$ to $g^2$ eventually.
Concatenating paths $P$, $gP$, $g^2P,\ldots,g^{n-1}P$ gives a nontrivial
closed path in the graph, so it cannot be a tree.